# Is it possible to install a full-blown desktop Linux distro on an Android smartphone?

Tags: linux, system-installation, android, smartphone

This may be a stupid question, but is there any way to overwrite Android with a full-blown desktop Linux distro on an Android smartphone?
I looked at a few tutorials, though they only seem to emulate Linux within Android.

So is there any way to fully install Linux as my only smartphone operating system, and if so, how?

Comment: In theory yes, in practice no. All the cheap android phones I and most people can afford use binary proprietary drivers for their graphics, for which there are no xorg equivalents. There probably are ways to run a proper linux distro _on top_ of Android, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

postmarketOS, is a distribution based on Alpine Linux for phones,

> A real Linux distribution for phones and other mobile devices.

https://postmarketos.org

The project is currently in alpha, but it can already boot and run on many devices.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one example is the ability to run [Ubuntu Phone](https://docs.ubuntu.com/phone/en/devices/) (aka Ubuntu Touch) on smartphones.

There are also [reports](https://www.unixmen.com/arch-linux-android-phone/) of installing Arch Linux on a smartphone.